# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

When I used `localStorage` for store `cart` item, then show me error in console box: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` like this, and my output is blank nothing to show,

I have tried like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from "../constants/cartConstants";

export const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      product: data._id,
      qty,
    },
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

In the `cartAction.js` file I have used `localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));` line.

then `store.js` file:

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducer/cartReducer";
import {
  productDetailsReducer,
  productListReducer,
} from "./reducer/productReducer";

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
      : [],
  },
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

If I'm not use this logic

```
cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
      : [],
  },
```

Inside `initialState` then does not show me any error, but when I used this then show me error.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Well the first thing for you to do is examine the string you're passing to `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: That is "u" as in "undefined".  You are making the mistake of assuming that dispatch will set the state synchronously.  If you `setItem` in a reducer instead of an action, you'll be able to set the localStorage properly.

Comment: Did you look at [any of the 288 other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+Unexpected+token+u+in+JSON+at+position+0) that reference this same error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you saved `undefined` into the storage because `getState().cart.cartItems` was undefined at some point.

This is a one-way route as you discovered, because `JSON.stringify(undefined)` will actually return `undefined` (not as string) but saving it into `localStorage` casts it to a string, ending up as `"undefined"`. Now `"undefined"` (unlike `""` or `undefined`) *is* truthy, so your check doesn't detect it as empty, but then `JSON.parse("undefined")` will fail because that's not valid JSON, hence the `"u"` at the start failing already.

It would be best to not try to store `undefined` at all (check for it first). Likely the state doesn't have the cart items yet at the time at which you try to read them, it sounds like an asynchronous timing issue (`dispatch` is asynchronous, the state won't change synchronously immedately after you called it). As jmargolisvt mentioned in the comments, try reading it in a reducer instead.

(Then make sure to delete the bad value from your local storage manually so your code can run again.)

But to avoid the situation where the app is just broken for the user and won't load until they delete their local site data (if they even think of that) - regardless of what caused it - I usually wrap `JSON.parse` with data from `localStorage` in a `try`/`catch` where I just consider exceptions as empty value, so at least the app will still work and just have lost the data.

Comment: Thank you!, When I'm clear my localStorage then show me another error, that look like: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: There is no call to `find` in the code you showed. If it's a new error it's best to open a new question with debugging details specifically for that error, including the stack and the code that contains the call which led to the error.

Comment: I'm trying to solved step by step with your answer, If solved then let you know, Thank you.